# matrix rotation segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Writing code for the matrix rotation question in hackerrank.  i am getting segmentation fault. the code is not complete. i have commented on the statements which i think is creating the prblem but cant identify the mistake . plz help.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct coord
    {
    int i,j;
    } starting, current;

struct reference
    {
    float i,j;
    } center;

int **a,m,n,t1,t2;    
int goup()
    {
    float dist,dist2;
    dist=sqrt((center.i-current.i)*(center.i-current.i)+(center.j-current.j)*(center.j-current.j));
    do
        {
        t1=a[current.i-1][current.j];
        a[current.i-1][current.j]=t2;//segmentation fault at this statement
        t2=t1;
        current.i--;
        dist=sqrt((center.i-current.i)*(center.i-current.i)+(center.j-current.j)*(center.j-current.j));

        } while(dist2!=dist);
    return 0;
    }

int main()
    {
    int t;
    cin>>m>>n>>t;
    a=new int*[m];
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        a[i]=new int[n];

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>a[i][j];

    center.i=(float)(m-1)/2.0;
    center.j=(float)(n-1)/2.0;
    starting.i = center.i + (0.5)*(m%2+1);
    starting.j = center.j + (0.5)*(n%2+1);
    current.i=starting.i;
    current.j=starting.j;
    t2=a[starting.i][starting.j];
    t1=a[starting.i-1][starting.j];

    while(current.i!=m)
        {
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
            {
            goup();
            // goleft();
            // godowm();
            // goright();
            }
        starting.i++;
        starting.j++;
        current.i=starting.i;
        current.j=starting.j;
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What does the variable 'dist2' represent? You are not initializing it (to be fair, you are never changing a value of it, so the loop runs for longer than expected, and crashes), so, it will have a random value. Did you even try running your code with a debugger attached?

Answer (score 1):

Since `dist2` is never initialised, `dist2!=dist` is rarely true and you decrement `current.i` so many times that you wind up accessing outside the array and dereferencing whatever random number might be lying around there.

It's impossible to say how to fix it since you haven't left any clue about what the function is supposed to accomplish.
Initialising `dist2` with whatever value you want it to have would be a good start, but the condition is still unlikely to ever be true.